# Get Coordinates 4 significant digits limitation

Tags: graphics, front-end

The tool "get coordinates" (clicking on a plot), seems to work with a fixed number of significant digits (4), in a way that we can quickly lose sensibility (the tool really becomes useless). The following example shows the problem:

```
Plot[a, {a, 1950, 1950.2}]
```

[image]

I imagine that this is a feature tending to the bug classification. Is there a way of correcting this behavior? (on 9.0.1)

Comment: Why don't you use `ClickPane[Plot[a, {a, 1950, 1950.2}], (pts = #) &]`?

Comment: I'd report it as a bug ...

Comment: Strangely using `CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"CopiedValueFunction" -> (# &)}` gives 6 digits.

Comment: @SimonWoods Strange indeed, especially considering that using `Identity` still gives only 4 (that's where I stopped looking at that option).

Comment: Strongly related MathGroups thread: "[Get Graphics Coordinates accuracy](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/fSgBOeDfJp8/LTZwv_UV5PYJ)." The solution suggested is `CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> (#&),
  "CopiedValueFunction" -> (SetPrecision[#, $MachinePrecision]&)}`.

Comment: Also related Wolfram Blog post: "[Get Coordinates: New in 6.0.2](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/03/11/get-coordinates-new-in-602/)."

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps:

```
Plot[a, {a, 1950, 1950.2}, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" ->  
    Function[pt, Row[{"point=", NumberForm[pt, 6]}]], 
   "CopiedValueFunction" -> Function[pt, pt]}]
```

of course you can change the "DisplayFunction".

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility, which increases the number of digits displayed is the following.
Define the two functions:

```
plotCopiedValueF[x_] := (SetPrecision[#, $MachinePrecision] & /@ x);
plotDisplayF[x_] := (InputForm /@ N[x]);

CoordinatesToolOptions -> {
    "CopiedValueFunction" -> plotCopiedValueF,
    "DisplayFunction" -> plotDisplayF
}
```

The result is shown below, and also the copied values have the same number of decimal digits:

> {
>   {3.3347506348627886652025154035`15.954589770191003,
>   {0.0433058311806071571936627151`15.954589770191003}
>   }

[image: Cursor]

Comment: This is quite strange.  Note that if you use `MachinePrecision` instead of `$MachinePrecision` then it does not work.

Comment: I think you forgot to change your function names in the `CoordinatesToolOptions`.

Comment: @user8074 on my computer, the copied values only have 6 significant digits (the displayed values are "complete"). It's much better than before, but why the difference with yours? (XP SP3 9.0.1)

Comment: @xzczd You are probably right: I changed my orgiginal names to clarify the meaning and possibly forgot to change them everywhere

Comment: @P.Fonseca I do not know: in my case it worked both under XP and Vista. I did not check on Win7 or Win8. I am rather accustomed to some inconsistences in MMA and often just stop at the first working solution without asking too much...

Comment: @Szabolcs, I tried with MachinePrecision and confirm your observation. Actually, the behavior seems "correct" for any precision *number* (also $MachinePrecision is a number), while MachinePrecision is a symbol and is probably handled differently internally. I can't say why.

Comment: @P.Fonseca It works for me if I use `SetPrecision` with anything *except* `MachinePrecision` (note the difference from `$MachinePrecision` which is a numerical value and will result in using Mma's built-in arbitrary precision with the same number of digits as machine precision---confusing? :-) Here's a piece of code to try: `Plot[x, {x, 1950, 1950.002}, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"CopiedValueFunction" -> (SetPrecision[#, 
       10] &)}]`.

Comment: Finally it works fine. My mistake :-(. Problem solved :-)